# Can i exchange limit and derivation for this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

i was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/v_HeaeUUOnc?t=1363) on extending the factorial and got confused about one step in particular. In 22:45 he claims the following:

$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left( \ln{\frac{k}{x+k}} \right) +x \cdot \ln N \right)=\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\left( \ln{\frac{k}{x+k}} \right)\right) +\frac{d}{dx} \left( x \cdot \ln N \right)  \right)$

To be able to swap derivative and the limit, the sequence has to be uniformly convergent. From a post i posted earlier, it appears not to be the case. Am i missing something?

My thoughts:

1. Is this step actually legal?
2. Is there any paper that derives the factorial as seen in video?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: The theorem you’re implicitly referring states that if the sequence of derivatives is uniformly convergent (plus additional hypothesis), the you can make the swap. It doesn’t state that it has to. I other words, it is a sufficient condition. By the way it is an interesting point to see if this is also a necessary condition. You also need to update your question with the domain you’re considering. Because the uniform convergence may happen on compact intervals. Which would be sufficient.

Comment: So i got that wrong! If i prove the right side uniformly convergent i can make the swap?

Comment: Yes… it is the right side that need to be uniformly convergent.